# Why SelectedIndexChanged fires for a DropDownList when a button is clicked?

Tags: .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate, autopostback

I have an ASP.NET `DropDownList` with `AutoPostBack=true` and `EnableViewState=false`. I have a button on the page that does nothing. If I change the selection in the ddl, it posts back , which is expected. If I click the button, the page posts back and the ddl's `SelectedIndexChanged` fires. Why does it get fired?

Answer (score 10):

Feedback from Microsoft :- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/103844/dropdownlist-always-fire-selectedindexchanged-event-when-viewstate-is-disabled-and-the-selected-item-is-not-changed-by-the-user

> "Thanks for your feedback. If
>   ViewState is disabled on the page or
>   on the DropDownList control, the
>   selected index cannot be saved, so
>   each postback looks like the selected
>   index has been changed. You can save
>   the selected index yourself and
>   compare against it to see if the
>   selection has really changed, or you
>   can enable ViewState on the
>   DropDownList. "

In your case the viewstate of the dropdownlist is false. Enable the same or you can compare index of the selected item as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling viewstate.  This is a common issue.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to enable viewstate you'll have to track the drop list value yourself, like this guy did [DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChange to 0th index w/out ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474367/dropdownlist-onselectedindexchange-to-0th-index-w-out-viewstate/475196#475196)

Answer (score 1):

If you load your ddl in page_load, when you click the button it goes page_load again and it loads ddl items again that changes selected index. But I don't know your code, so this is an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I found my problem was that I called my Render function `Page_Load`.

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
```

I completely missed the fact that the page loaded `Page_Load` as a default load function, then loaded it again when it ran prerender.  I changed it to the following, and now the function is only called once:

```
Sub Renderer(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
```